# Adding an overlay to a google map

Tags: overlay, photo

I made my own google map with historical information (of houses and people in the 50-s in Princenhage, The Netherlands):
https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=174YNyi2hs_iVpoU0qLqOPq-YUxI&ll=51.57704585455824%2C4.737584814456795&z=18

Now I would like to add an aerial photograph of 1950 as an extra layer on this map so that my map looks as 'google earth in 1950'.

Is this possible and how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you need to make a baseMap of your aerial photo. If you managed that you can use this example to add the basemap to your viewer:

https://github.com/rcknr/basemap-google-maps

Comment: So two steps: 1 making a basemap. How to do that? 2. Entering the codes. How do i find and edit the code in google maps?